# canOpenURL when returns false prints out an unnecessary error message

Tags: ios, objective-c, openurl, ios-urlsheme

I am using **canOpenURL** to open the app if installed in the device. And added the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** to whitelist the Schemes. But when canOpenURL returns false It always prints out an unnecessary error message in the console log. Below is the error message I receive.

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "XXXX://XXXXXXXXXXXXX" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)
```

As I am using multiple schemes in my application, and my customer does not want these error message logs. Is there any way I can avoid printing these warning/log message to console.

[This is the radar link(similar issue)](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5063868615229440). Its closed without any solution.

Currently I am using iOS 11.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: @am449 add your console log

Comment: aaded the log message @MahendraGP

Comment: The error code -10814 means `No application in the Launch Services database matches the input criteria.`

Comment: http://www.osstatus.com/ check for quick information, input your statuscode there

Comment: I want to avoid printing these log message to console. And this happen only when the return false.

Answer (score 0):

Seems an intended syslog by Apple mentioned in their WWDC presentation

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/703/?time=576

Answer (score 0):

This does not print to device log. As its printing only in the debug area, we can ignore it.